# Redis doesn't save data

Tags: database, redis, persistence

I've enabled 'appendonly' value in redis.conf but Redis still cant't save data on disk. I want to save data whenever something is changing in database. I can't lose data even if I kill Redis server. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Check your configuration (especially the dir parameter: Redis must have R/W access rights to this directory). If you cannot loose data even if the server is killed, don't use Redis at all. It is an in-memory store, not a disk-based transaction engine.

Comment: I think access to the directory is not problem because when I use SHUTDOWN command on redis it's saving data.
http://redis.io/topics/persistence
Here is something about persistence but it doesn't work for me (I guess it's my fault but I don't know what is wrong...)

Comment: aof_enabled:0
ohhh I see this when I use INFO command... Why?

Comment: ./redis-cli CONFIG SET appendonly yes //now aof_enabled value is 1 :)

Comment: Because you have not restarted the instance? Use the "config set appendonly yes" command to activate it online.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem whoever is that when you "config set appendonly yes" it only changes the running instance. When you start rdis-server.exe it starts a new instance because no config file is specified. To fix this obviously is to use

CMD: "C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-server.exe conf/redis.conf"

make sure you run cmd in administrator mode aswell.

Now you can edit settings in redis.conf which will be loaded on the start.